# how do i use the voicent api in java to make calls?

Tags: java, api

hello I am using this api and how do i use this?

[https://www.voicent.com/devnet/docs/javaapi.htm#:~:text=String%20reqId%20%3D%20callText](https://www.voicent.com/devnet/docs/javaapi.htm#:%7E:text=String%20reqId%20%3D%20callText)

```
Voicent v = new Voicent();
    v.callAudio("1234567", "Hello", true);
```

I am using this code but i get so many errors

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:498)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:246)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:351)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:373)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1057)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1430)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1401)
at application.Voicent.postToGateway(Voicent.java:198)
at application.Voicent.callAudio(Voicent.java:98)
at callnumber.test.main(test.java:10)
```

how do I use this api?

Comment: Do you have a Voicent Gateway running on `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> all these functions are implemented as a HTTP client communicating
> directly with Voicent Gateway, they can be run on any machine that has
> a connection to the host running the gateway

Further down the page, you'll see that default constructor you're using is connecting to localhost. Presumably, you have nothing running locally on that port, resulting in the "Connection refused" error you see.

```
public class Voicent
{
  /**
   * Constructor with default localhost:8155
   */
  public Voicent()
  {
    host_ = "localhost";
    port_ = 8155;
  }
```

You need to setup the gateway somewhere first, then connect to it.

Comment: ok thank you, what port do i use tho?

Comment: @EnzoSebastian Whatever port the gateway configured to use. Presumably 8155 is the default, judging from the constructor.